Не отображается виджет Telegram Login на странице React
У меня есть вот такая страница:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainPage = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-login="ТУТ УКАЗАН БОТ" data-size="large" data-radius="5" data-auth-url="ТУТ УКАЗАН ДОМЕН" data-request-access="write"></script>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MainPage;

Но почему то этот виджет вообще не отображается. Сайт стоит на хостинге с доменом. Всё как надо. Но он просто не появляется. Прошу помощи

В HTML разметке появляется указанный тэг?

Да, в разметке есть точно тоже самое, что и выше в коде, таже самая строка

Как вариант, попробуйте добавить этот тег script на обычну статичную HTML страничку - что получится? И нет ли ошибок в консоли?

Да! Если на простой html странице это вставить - кнопка появляется, но в реакте её нету. Как это можно исправить?

На самом деле я хз. Я бы начал с изучения логов в консоли. Там скрипт еще делает всякие сетевые запросы. Возможно есть виджет под реакт и поведение как то связано с внутренним механизмом реакта. Но в целом, такого, визуально, быть не должно(мануал не читал, достоверно не знаю)

В принципе ответ не заставил себя ждать, react не обрабатывает вставку скриптов в компоненты. Реализовал вот так:
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainPage = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22";
        script.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', "ТУТ НАЗВАНИЕ БОТА");
        script.setAttribute('data-size', "large");
        script.setAttribute('data-radius', "5");
        script.setAttribute('data-auth-url', "ТУТ ОБРАТНЫЙ ЮРЛ");
        script.setAttribute('data-request-access', "write");
        script.async = true;
        ref.current.appendChild(script);
    }, [cookies, navigate]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={ref} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default MainPage;


Только убедитесь, что у вас [cookies, navigate] не меняются во время жизни проекта, иначе будете получать дубли виджета. Может стоит пустой массив зависимостей оставить, что бы установка происходила только при первом рендере компонента?

не изменяется, спасибо за направление в нужную сторону)

Ну чем смог :) Заодно и у себя освежил в памяти(или дополнил) знания
